# Python 3: How to load multiple CSVs in AWS S3 into a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python

I'm working on an AWS EMR Notebook connected to an EMR cluster. I am normally used to working in Scala and loading AWS S3 directories with thousands of CSVs into a Spark DataFrame. However, I'm unable to emulate that same approach using Python 3.

I have at least a thousand `csv` files like so:

```
s3://dir/part-00000-d27fd1c5-96d0-431c-88d8-4b216fe008d5-c000.csv
s3://dir/part-00001-d27fd1c5-96d0-431c-88d8-4b216fe008d5-c000.csv
...
s3://dir/part-12345-...
```

I tried each of these three approaches, where each approach is separated by a new line:

```
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob('s3://dir/*.csv')))

df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob(os.path.join('', "s3://dir/*.csv"))))

path = r's3://dir'                     # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))     # advisable to use os.path.join as this makes concatenation OS independent
df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files)
concatenated_df   = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
```

each gives the error: `ValueError: No objects to concatenate`

**Troubleshooting Hints**

In the case of the last solution, I notice that `all_files` is an empty list:

```
path = r's3://dir'                     # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))     # advisable to use os.path.join as this makes concatenation OS independent
all_files
[]
```

Also, I tried:

```
os.listdir(path)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 's3://dir'
```

Of course, the directory exists as I can see the CSV files in this S3 directory. I did not mistype it either, as I am simply copying-pasting. Hence, this suggests that perhaps I am unable to view it from the EMR cluster.

Note, I am able to load a single CSV like so:

```
df = pd.read_csv('s3://dir/part-00000-d27fd1c5-96d0-431c-88d8-4b216fe008d5-c000.csv')
df
```

But this is obviously hard/inefficient to manually do for each of the thousand csv files that I have.

Any ideas on what else to try or how to debug this?

Comment: You're globbing over `s3://` virtual hosted-style URLs - do you have something installed that actually resolves these for you?

Comment: I don't think this is enough, see [here](https://medium.com/@victor.perez.berruezo/download-a-csv-file-from-s3-and-create-a-pandas-dataframe-in-python-ffdb08c2967c) on how to connect to s3, you can then modify that code to do it within a loop.

Comment: @cs95 I'm working on an AWS EMR Notebook connected to an EMR cluster. I am normally used to working in Scala and loading S3 directories with thousands of CSVs into a Spark DataFrame. However, I'm unable to emulate that same approach using Python 3.

Comment: Yes but have you tried authenticating your session with python? Just because the notebook is connected doesn't necessarily mean the python shell can access it without authentication.

Comment: @cs95 not sure what you mean by "authenticating my session with python." What would that look like? I have another notebook open with a Spark kernel and am able to access the same S3 directory.

Comment: Try enclosing your `map` function with `list`: `pd.concat(list(map(pd.read_csv, files)))`. Or using a `list comprehension`: `[pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files]`.

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva thanks. I actually noticed that `all_files` is an empty list. Thinking I'm doing something wrong with the `glob` with respect to the S3 directories.

Answer (score 0):

if you have same columns in all your `.CSV` files, then this might just workout for you.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:\DRO\DCL_rawdata_files' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Here, I  have added `header=0` so that after reading `.CSV` first row can be assigned as the column names.

Comment: Gives the same error as the other things I tried (see post).